# Runge kutta 4th order computation of force solving 2nd order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

\begin{equation}
 \frac{dx}{dt} = v 
 \end{equation}
 \begin{equation}
 m .\frac{dv}{dt}= F_{p }(x)+F_{g}(v,x)
 \end{equation}

Conside I am solving the above two equations using runge kutta 4th order as below:

**Method Runge Kutta $4^{th}$ order**

\begin{equation}
x^{'}=x_{0}+ \frac{1}{6}(k_{0}+2k_{1}+2k_{2}+k_{3})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v^{'}=v_{0}+ \frac{1}{6}(l_{0}+2l_{1}+2l_{2}+l_{3})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k_0 = h v_0 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
l_0 = \frac {h (F_{p}(x_0) +F_g(x_0,v_0)) }{ m}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k_1 = h (v_0+ \frac{l_0}{2}) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
l_1 = \frac {h (F_{p + w}(x_0 + \frac {k_0}{2}) +F_g(x_0 + \frac {k_0}{2}, v_0 + \frac {l_0}{2})) }{ m}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k_2 = h  (v_0+ \frac{ l_1}{2}) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
l_2 = \frac {h (F_{p}(x_0 + \frac {k_1}{2}) +F_g(x_0 + \frac {k_1}{2}, v_0 + \frac {l_1}{2})) }{ m}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k_3 = h  (v_0+ {l_2}) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
l_3 = \frac {h (F_{p}(x_0 +  {k_2}) +F_g(x_0 +  {k_2},v_0 + {l_2})) }{ m}
\end{equation}

So I get the velocity and position at the end, but what is the Force at that time-step and position for the particle?

Comment: The force is $F_p+F_g$: since it depends only on $x$ and $v$, you should be able to compute them.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you mean to say I compute it at the end with the values of x and v I get from rk4?

Comment: Actually, you need to compute the force inside each RK4 step, but more generally you can compute the force whenever you know a $x,v$ pair. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Okay I am simulating a dynamical model of humans. The $F_g$ is updated every $0.5$ seconds while $F_p$ every 0.01 second. I wish to compute the $F_p$ at each $timestep =0.01 sec$